# File permission in cygwin

Tags: linux, cygwin

I have following user who is the owner of the file:
[image]

I have another user called visitor (shown below) who do not belong to Administrators group, but he is still having write and other permission.
[image]

How do i enable file permission only to the owner and other users belonging to Administrators group in Cygwin and restrict to other users? I am assuming the setting I have provided will restrict write permission to all other users except arjunkhadka and any users that belong to Administrators group. Am I missing something??

Comment: does `chmod 770 test.txt` works ?

Comment: It doesn't. but chmod 750 works and at least do not allow write to other users